# How to print all data from an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I just started with C, i cant find out how to print all values from an array with for loop, wether it is array of strings or integers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int array[3][20] = {10, 15, 20};

    for (int i = 0; i < array; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What mistake do i make here?

Comment: What is `i < array` supposed to mean? `array` is an array, not a number. Are you trying to get the length of the array?

Comment: Yes you are right i was missing length...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a 2-dimensional array, you should use nested loops for each dimension, and access the elements using 2 indexes.

To get the number of elements in an array use `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof array[0]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof array[i] / sizeof array[i][0]; j++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Initially i thought to iterate over array of strings, so 20 in this line "int array[3][20]" was meant to determine length of each element of an array. But i guess it is unnecessary for array of integers?    
I have manage trough your answer to came up with this solution:
```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

 int array[3] = {10, 15, 20};

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof array[i]; i++)
 {
  printf("%d\n", array[i]);
 }

 return 0;
}
```
Thank you.

Comment: Right. A string is an array of characters, so it needs a second dimension. But integers are just single elements.